# Action not being hit from another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am asking a simple login page to get the user to enter a pin on a mobile responsive app its in house not online.

When the page is posted the user clicks the submit button the SaveUsers is the function that is called first this is on the Login Controller.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult SaveUsers(Users model)
{
        BrianScott_SOMEntities usr = new BrianScott_SOMEntities();
        var s = usr.GetUsers(model.Pin);

        var item = s.FirstOrDefault();
        if (item == "Success")
        {
            var sageDetails = usr.Users.Where(w => w.Pin ==model.Pin).FirstOrDefault();

            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("BScotSalesOrderManagerLogin");
            cookie.Values.Add("SageUserName", sageDetails.SageUserName.ToString());
            cookie.Values.Add("SagePassword", sageDetails.SagePassWord.ToString());
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

            return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");

    }
    else if (item == "User Does not Exists")

    {
       ViewBag.NotValidUser = item;

    }
    else
    {
       ViewBag.Failedcount = item;
     }
   return View("Index.cshtml");
}
```

The below form is the form that is represented with the above controller which prompts the user for their pin number.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@model Web.SOM.Models.Users


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div class="bs-example" style="border:2px solid gray;">
    <label>@ViewBag.SageUserName</label>
    <div class="form-group centerlook">
        <h1> Login </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group centerlook">
        <label>Pin: </label>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pin  )*
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pin)
    </div>
            <div class="form-group error">
        @if (@ViewBag.Failedcount != null)
        {

            <label> Failed Attempt count is: @ViewBag.Failedcount</label>
        }

        @if (@ViewBag.NotValidUser != null)
        {

            <label> @ViewBag.NotValidUser</label>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="loginbtn">

        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />

    </div>
</div>
}
```

The home controller is what the controller in the first piece of codes redirects to it is the index action to which I want to hit.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
 if (Request.Cookies["BScotSalesOrderManagerLogin"] != null)
 {
            ViewBag.SageUserName = Request.Cookies["BScotSalesOrderManagerLogin"].Values["SageUserName"];
            ViewBag.SagePassword = Request.Cookies["BScotSalesOrderManagerLogin"].Values["SagePassword"];
  }
 return View();
}
```

But the method is not getting hit unless I do a hard reload is there another way of moving to the other view and making sure that the index method is being hit ?.

Because when I look at the viewbag the items are null when they should contain a username and a password of the related row when I debug on the first page the values are their but then lost on the other page.

On my page i am wanting to display the information I am just doing

```
<label>Sage Username : @ViewBag.SageUserName </label>
```

But the value is blank? I am coming from a web forms background so please excuse me better late than never jumping ship

Comment: What method is not being hit?

Comment: `return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");` Why are you doing this vs `RedirectToAction`?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the sequence of HTTP requests is here, or if these actions are in different controllers, etc.  Can you clarify the specific steps that the user is taking and how these code snippets relate to each other?  In that sequence, what specifically is happening and where specifically is it failing?

Comment: @mjwills that appears to work but the label is not outputting anything is there anything else i have to do other than use the ViewBag that way ?

Comment: @david: You're bouncing between controllers and manually returning views associated with other controllers.  When the form posts, it's looking for `Index` in its current controller context, which is `Login`.  There's nothing telling it that it should be looking for `Home`.  Specify that in the `Html.BeginForm()`, specify it in any links, etc.  You'll find that redirects make this much simpler than manually overriding the returned view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sequence of events is...

- User POSTs to `SaveUsers` on `Login` (aliased as the action `Index`)
- You return a view
- User POSTs from that view to `Index`, *still on `Login`*

When you do this:

```
return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
```

You're essentially *overriding* the framework's standard behavior.  You're returning a specific file to be used as the view, but not telling the framework to switch any context or change the URL in any way.  So from the *browser's* perspective, even though you returned a view from your server-side `Home` folder, the page is still `/Login/Index` and any form actions, links, etc. will be from there.

In general you should prefer redirects to manually specifying views.  So a sensible sequence of events might be:

- User POSTs to `SaveUsers` on `Login` (aliased as the action `Index`)
- Server-side code performs its logic, redirects the user to `Index` on `Home`
- User GETs `Index` on `Home`
- Server returns the view
- User POSTs to `Index` on `Home`

So your `SaveUsers` action method, when successful, can do something like:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

This will then cause the user to make a GET request to `Index` on `Home`, which can just `return View()` and that will default to the view you're manually returning now.  Now from the browser's perspective it's on `/Home/Index` and all form actions, links, etc. will be from that context.

Additionally, if you always want a given form, link, etc. to point to a specific controller action regardless of where it was loaded from, you can specify that.  For example, when you do this:

```
using (Html.BeginForm())
```

You are telling the framework that this form will "POST to the current URL, whatever that URL is".  But when you do this:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
```

This tells the framework that the form will always post to the `Index` action on the `Home` controller, regardless of the current URL.

Answer (score 2):

can you try using

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(yourActionName, yourControllerName))
{

}
```

And use `RedirectToAction` to return to your Home Index..

Comment: While I appreciate your answer this is not the stack overflow process when such a low reputation to create an answer when you cannot comment.

Comment: New to the community, Thanks for being nice. I totally did not see the add comment option